# Best practice for handling one tcp connection on a android device with many activities

Tags: android, service, tcp, android-asynctask, singleton

Please let me explain my problem first. 
I've got a server using a tcp-ip socket connection with a custom protocol based on byte streams. The client, an android app, implements the protocol too, of course. But, both need to communicate in both ways, reading from the other peer and writing out to it. On the server it was no problem, but the android client crushes my head.
What I want is basically a way of how the android client is establishing a tcp connection the server when starting the app and (re)-using it in every activity to send and receive data.

I read this: [Android TCP connection best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975080/android-tcp-connection-best-practice)
and of course the discussion when to use a service and a singleton. 
Still I am not sure how apps like the facebook app on android does such things. Okay, they might use REST instead of a plain bytestream tcp connection, but when opening the app, it starts receiving data and when finished data (could be the newsstream) is rendered and displayed. Looks like AsyncTasks, doens't it?

So my questions are...:

1. How could such a app look like? - How to realize this way of communication (with AsyncTasks or just as a separate Thread?)? So do I need to implement in every activity one or more AsyncTasks? - In this case, i want every AsyncTask to use the Socket and its streams from a singleton. Is that possible?
2. Do you have any good example project to this topic?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this topic recently, having pretty much the same use case as you, with one difference: I implemented multiple concurrent TCP socket connections, which was a lot of work, but in the end it worked like a charm.

In my opinion, AsyncTask are no valid option. They can have advantages, if you want to transfer fix-sized data collections like Image Folders or big files, while keeping the user up-to-date with the current progress. For a flexible communication it is easier to work with Threads.

The proper way to make "ConnectionThreads" reusable for multiple activities is a "ConnectionService". Your activites can subscribe to this [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)  and ask it to open a connection to the server. Once connected, the service keeps the connection, even if the activity is paused/destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking about your statement about flexibility when using separate thread instead of AsyncTasks. Maybe you can specify this point a little more? - I'm curious about it, because I see only the following points being an advantage of a separate thread: building/closing the connection only one time, separating a defined range of functionality (rather good design practice)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I use services to do the actual requests and then place the information on a database.
On the activity I show the data I want using cursors, so when the database is updated the activity is updated automatically.

Here is a [io 2010 presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) on how the first twitter app was done

I don't know if [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) works in your case, but you should take a look. There's an [io 2013 presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJOOTFfYzhR2d-rcSbBbEE_&index=3) about Volley